# Why does boxplot() affect bullet point index size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

The following scatter graph with a newly added boxplot() overlay changes the size of 'size='. The bullet points indexing size has increased.

```
ggplot(stats, aes(x=Genre, y=Gross...US,size=Budget...mill.))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=Studio)) +  
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = Studio))
```

Here is a picture of the scattergraph with boxplot overlay:

[image]

Highlighted in the picture above is the issue of increased size with the bullet points "Budget...mill."

EDIT: Issue resolved.
The size=Budget...mill. needed to be placed inside of geom_point().

```
ggplot(stats, aes(x=Genre, y=Gross...US))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=Studio,**size=Budget...mill.**)) +  
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = Studio))
```

Comment: @www as you can see in the image the bullet points have a grey graph around them, caused by the boxplot and I don't know why. The sizes should match

Comment: @www If I remove boxplot() [this is what the graph shows up like](https://i.imgur.com/BMtW43D.png). The bullet points are the size they should be. Thanks for the help though, I understand.

Comment: Move your "EDIT" below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. The size=Budget...mill. needed to be placed inside of geom_point().

```
ggplot(stats, aes(x=Genre, y=Gross...US))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=Studio,**size=Budget...mill.**)) +  
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = Studio))`
```